# How to get the system wide list separator on Windows

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pywin32

I use pandas to convert csv to more usable datatypes.
The problem is that csv files doesn't need to be separated by commas. The separator (between cells) is defined by the operating system (at least under Windows), and when the system wide list separator differs from comma, pandas (or anything else I tried) cannot determine what separator should be used.
Sure, I can make a twocell csv file with pywin or something, and get the separator, but isn't there a direct way to do this?

Below you can see the txt representation of two csv files, which are displayed identically on Windows machines, where respectively "," and ";" are the default list separators.

- test,1,2,"My name is Bond, James Bond",My age is; 41
- test;1;2;My name is Bond, James Bond;"My age is; 41"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Python's built in `Sniffer` class to detect the CSV's delimiters. Here's an example [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer):

```
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:

    #detect the delimiter used
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024))

    #return to the beginning of the file
    csvfile.seek(0)

    #file should now open with the correct delimiter.
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas should handle files with different separators fine, just use the `sep` argument to `read_csv`:

```
# Don't actually need the sep argument here
# as comma is the default
df1 = pandas.read_csv('csv_with_commas.csv', sep=',')
# Change the sep argument if your file uses a different
# separator
df2 = pandas.read_csv('csv_with_semicolons.csv', sep=';')
```

Comment: Sure, I can do that on my computer, but how can I know what separator to use on someone else's machine?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you might have been overcomplicating things based on your statement that pandas "cannot handle" those files properly.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't clear enough there. I edited the question to be more precise. Thanks for your help anyway!